# HTTPS SSL only on Checkout and Login, Not on all pages on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ssl, https

When you put secure URLs on frontend to yes in Magento 2, it's now programmed to make all front end urls with https.

The website we have already had top rankings. We don't benefit from the SEO boost from https at this moment. And we know that when you change HTTP site to https, your rankings drop and it can take months before it recovers.

Now I'm upgrading from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and I only want the checkout in login pages to be HTTPS. (because Chrome en fire fox show "unsecure" which fears the client from logging in).

How can this be done? I feel Magento had to program the option for one to choose if they want only checkout, login or all pages instead of the following Google like slaves. The data shows, Google is lying about the fact that you don't have any SEO problems...

I have all position 1 rankings, even if it drops to  3 or 4 for 5 months...it hurts the business.

I hope someone can help me.

So by having only the important pages secure, the ranking's won't hurt and the client knows they are safe.

Comment: We had some very competitive products with #1 SERP and I made redirect 301s in the htaccess to the new https pages. For a day/2 we went down to #3 and now we're back to #1 - better than Amazon and the manufacturer again. We lost more sales with the little yellow triangle warning as I couldn't get non secure pages to stop showing errors.

Comment: Even if it takes 1 month, i would not worry, but i read on forums, that it takes 5-6 months...and even then it was not recovered so i was confused. That's the reason i was scared.

Comment: Maybe it's different for everyone, but I've read that a lot of the things I do "shouldn't work" and yet I'll have #1 SERP. 

I have one page that ranks exceptionally well and provides a good deal bit of revenue from Google Ads and it doesn't use keywords, description or any meta tags at all. According to most of the SEO experts I've read, that page shouldn't even be on 1st page, much less #1.

Personally, I think if the content is there, it doesn't really matter a whole lot, especially if all you're doing is changing to https. For us, the error and the "insecure page" hurt us more.

Comment: But also, and this is probably a BIG reason, the domain is about 26 years old - so there's that ...

Comment: Our domain is 4 years old. I just wish there was an option where i could choose to HTTPS the checkout page or the full pages...i don't understand why they just changed all to HTTPS.